# Odoo one2many view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am beginner in Odoo and python, and I want to create a simple module, which should insert some categories for a person (student, employee,...), and then insert persons with field category. My question is, how to create p_c_view.xml. I tried to adjust some xmls examples that I found, but had no success. Here is my p_c.py file. Thanks

```
 class p_c_person(osv.osv):
        _name = "p_c.person"
        _description = "Person"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Persone', size=128, required=True),
            'categories': fields.one2many('p_c.category', 'category_id', 'Categories'
        }

    p_c_person()

    class p_c_category(osv.osv):
        _name = "p_c.category"
        _description = "Category"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Category', size=128, required=True),
            'property_id': fields.many2one('p_c.person', 'Person Name', select=True),
        }

    p_c_category()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Many2one**

Store a relation against a co-model:

Specific options:

- **comodel_name**: name of the opposite model
- **delegate**: set it to True to make fields of the target model accessible from the current model (corresponds to _inherits)

**Example**:

```
'property_id': fields.many2one('p_c.person', 'Person Name', select=True),
```

**One2many**

Store a relation against many rows of co-model:

Specific options:

- **comodel_name**: name of the opposite model
- **inverse_name**: relational column of the opposite model

**Example**:

```
'categories': fields.one2many('p_c.category', 'property_id', 'Categories'),
```

Refer [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#fields)

`One2many` field only created for relational `many2one` field of that model, it gives you freedom to travelling bi-directional. Odoo engine manage integrity while you create record in reference model in which you have define `many2one` field then you will see the effect in `one2many` field as well.

Answer (score 4):

*one2many* field takes responding *many2one* field with that object.

try with this code

```
class p_c_person(osv.osv):
    _name = "p_c.person"
    _description = "Person"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Persone', size=128, required=True),
        'categories': fields.one2many('p_c.category', 'property_id', 'Categories'
    }

p_c_person()

class p_c_category(osv.osv):
    _name = "p_c.category"
    _description = "Category"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Category', size=128, required=True),
        'property_id': fields.many2one('p_c.person', 'Person Name', select=True),
    }

p_c_category()
```

For more details you may visit [odoo documentation.](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html)