# Custom view of model inside the form view

Tags: view, model, odoo

I have this two models EstatePropertyModel and AuthorsModel, and I would like to display the entries of the AuthorsModel in the form of the EstatePropertyModel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

<record id="view_estate_property_advertisement_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">estate.property.form</field>
    <field name="model">estate.property</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      name="name"/>
      name="description"/>
      name="postcode"/>
      name="date_availability"/>
      name="expected_price"/>
      name="selling_price"/>
      name="bedrooms"/>
      name="living_area"/>
      name="facades"/>
      name="garage"/>
      name="garden"/>
      name="garden_area"/>
      name="garden_orientation"/>
      name="state_property"/>
      name="active"/>
      <field name="author_ids" position="after">
      <div class="oe_title">Authors</div>
      <div class="oe_subtitle">
      <t t-if="len(record.author_ids) == 0">No authors</t>
      <t t-if="len(record.author_ids) &gt; 0">
          <t t-foreach="record.author_ids" t-as="author">
              <span t-field="author.name"/>
          </t>
      </t>
     </div>
  </field>
</odoo>
```

Is this possible?
I am new in the odoo development, and I am asking to point me the direction where to look!

Thanks

Comment: You create a widget that uses [rpcs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_reference.html#widget) to get data from another model.

Answer (score 0):

yeeah it's possible through [One2many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388333/odoo-one2many-view#:%7E:text=One2many%20field%20only%20created%20for,in%20one2many%20field%20as%20well.) field in odoo, after that, create a `Notebook` in the form view in that notebook and create a `page`, on that page add the one2many view in it
it will be made like this...

```
<notebook>
    <page>
        <field name="one2many_field_name">
            <tree string="Example" editable="bottom">
                <field name="field_1_from_2nd_model"/>
                <field name="field_2_from_2nd_model"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

as per the comment below the answer is below this:

```
class ExampleModelFirst(models.Model):
    _name = 'first.model'

    field_1 = fields.Char(string='Field 1')
    field_2 = fields.Integer(string='Field 2')

class ExampleModelSecond(models.Model):
    _name = 'second.model'
    
    field_3 = fields.Many2one('first.model', string='reference')
    field_4 = fields.Char(related='field_3.field_1')
    field_5 = field.Integer(related='field_3.field_2')
```

Add these `second.model` field in form view you will get the values...

Comment: Without the One2Many relation is not possible, @Sidharth Panda?

Comment: you want to display or you want to create from another model too??, if you want to display then possible

Comment: I want to display! Can you point me the direction?

Comment: I don't understand it!

Comment: i am editing the answer wait

Comment: Without relation between the Models, it is possible ?

Comment: no, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

author_ids should be one2many field

To create a One2many field you can refer to this https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/08_relations.html#one2many

Do this if you want to show all fields

```
<notebook>
    <page string="Authors">
        <field name="author_ids"/>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Do this if you want to show specific fields

```
<notebook>
    <page string="Authors">
        <field name="author_ids">
           <tree>
              <field name="name"/>
           </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```